# Unable to understand the relation between Field Extensions, Polynomial Quotient Rings generated by Ideals, & Polynomial Roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field, quotient-group, polynomial-rings

I am going through this video [302.S2a: Field Extensions and Polynomial Roots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iapBh4EjfM&list=PLL0ATV5XYF8DTGAPKRPtYa4E8rOLcw88y&index=32) by
Matthew Salomone & there is a lot in this video which confuses me.

1. I understand the construction by which he generates the field with 8 elements {$0, 1, t, 1 + t, t^2, 1 + t^2, t + t^2, 1 + t + t^2$}. He sets $p(t) = 0$ & constructs a set with those 8 elements. But I am unable to figure out why he is calling this field as $F_2[t]/\langle p(t) \rangle$ - I am assuming this is the same as calling it $F_2[t]/\langle t^3 + t + 1 \rangle$

$F_2[x]/\langle t^3 + t + 1 \rangle$ is the Quotient Ring generated by the ideal $t^3 + t + 1$ - it doesn't contain these 8 elements at all. Each element of the Quotient Ring isn't even a polynomial - it's an equivalence class of polynomials - for e.g. one such element of $F_2[x]/\langle t^3 + t + 1 \rangle$  is this equivalence class $[\bar t]$

$[\bar t]$ = {$...-t^3+1, t, t^3 + 1,  t + 2, ...$}

Another element is this equivalence class below

$[\bar 5]$ = {$..., -t, 1, t^3 +t , 1, ...$}

So now why is he calling that field of 8 elements as $F_2[x]/\langle t^3 + t + 1 \rangle$ - isn't that a totally different ring/field?

I don't understand where the quotient construction using an ideal comes in here at all. We construct this new field by 2 things by just setting $t^3 + t + 1 = 0$ in $F_2[x]$. We don't need to use the ideal or the quotient ring generated by the ideal at all for this.

2. A little further into the video, timestamp 7:30 - he says $t$ is a root of the polynomial. Again I don't understand what he means by $t$ is a root of a polynomial $p(t)$ - for a polynomial $p(t)$, we always say $t = something$ is a root - what exactly does saying $t$ is a root mean?

Comment: Can't be bother to check, but I rather suspect that he calls it $K=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$. If we denote the coset $x+\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$ by $t$, then we have, indeed, $t^3+t+1=0$ and
$$K=\{0,1,t,t+1,t^2,t^2+1,t^2+t, t^2+t+1\}.$$ Observe the different roles of $t$ and $x$. With that difference clear it makes perfect sens to call $t$ a zero of the polynomial $x^3+x+1$. Personally I use a Greek letter in place of $t$, $\alpha$ being the default.

Comment: In this field $5=1$. At least after you have become familiar enough not to become confused you earn the privilege to drop the bar on top :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - your explanation kind of makes sense but a couple of things 1) He doesn't use $x$ at all in the video. He starts this part of the problem with this https://imgur.com/0LXGAEi.png at 5:04

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen 2) I feel a little confused about the concept of a root which is a variable - a root is always a constant in my mind! For e.g. the roots of $t^2-4$  are {2, -2} - I am unable to understand how either $[\bar x]$ or $t$ - can be a root of $t^3 + t + 1$. I am not sure if calling it $\alpha$ helps! If $\alpha$ is a constant, then it has only one value - so why use something like $\alpha$

Comment: Think of it just like any other element. It is just a name. Consider the quotient ring $K=\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$. This time let's denote the coset $x+\langle x^2-2\rangle$ by $\alpha$. We see that $\alpha^2-2$ is the coset $x^2-2+\langle x^2-2\rangle$, which is the same coset as $0+\langle x^2-2\rangle$. That is, the zero element of $K$. So
$$\alpha^2-2=0\in K.$$ Consequently some might want to give $\alpha$ the name $\sqrt2$. Of course, it has nothing whatsoever to do with the real number $1.4142135\ldots$, but that's not the point.

Comment: (cont'd) The point is that using quotient rings we can construct a bigger field where a given irreducible polynomial has a root. By the way, do note that the $\alpha$ in the previous comment could equally well be $-\sqrt2$. There is no natural way to call elements of $K$ positive or negative (unless we introduce a homomorphism from $K$ to $\Bbb{R}$ that can then be used for such a purpose).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - the roots of $x^2 -2$ are $\sqrt 2$ and $i\sqrt 2$. They are present in $\mathbb C$. And those values in $\mathbb C$ are the same as the values {1.4142135..., i*1.4142135...}. Isn't the point of constructing an extension field to have a field which is bigger $\mathbb R$ but smaller than $\mathbb C$ but it still contains {1.4142135,  i*1.4142135...}. If we construct an extension field which does contain the roots but it's not the same as {1.4142135...,  i*1.4142135...}, then I don't get what is the point of this construction.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  How do we get a different root which is not the same as {1.4142135...,  i*1.4142135...} in this extension field?. Or does it mean that a polynomial of degree n has n roots in $\mathbb C$ but these four roots can be something different in other fields. Or have I misunderstood what you mean by "it has nothing whatsoever to do with the real number 1.4142135"

Comment: Yes, the roots are something else in other fields. $x+\langle x^2-2\rangle$ has no decimal value. At least not before we map that field into the real numbers. But we don't really care. That's why the result on the uniqueness (up to isomorphism) of the splitting field is kinda powerful. Anyway, when doing exact arithmetic we only rely on the fact that $\sqrt2$ is a zero of the polynomial $x^2-2$. We don't use real approximations here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^3+x+1=p(x)$ is irreducible in $F_2[x]$ so  $\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $F_2[x]$. It follows that $F_2[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle=:S$ is a field. Note that this is where $\langle p(x) \rangle$ being an ideal (maximal ideal in this case) is used.

$S$ actually has $8$ elements in it. The elements of $S$ look like $ax^2+bx+c+\langle p(x) \rangle$, where $a,b$ and $c$ are in $F_2$. The elements of $S$ are often written with the bar notation (in such notation, $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is dropped) as $\overline {ax^2+bx+c}$, i.e., $\overline {ax^2+bx+c}=ax^2+bx+c+\langle p(x) \rangle$.

Now, regard every element in $F_2[x]$ as an element of $S$ (using the bar notation).

With this view point, $\overline x\in S$ is a zero of $p(t)\in S$ as the following shows:

\begin{align}
p(\overline x)=(\overline x)^3+\overline x+1&=(x+\langle p(x)\rangle)^3+(x+\langle p(x)\rangle)+1\\
&=x^3+x+1+\langle p(x)\rangle\\&=p(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle=\langle p(x)\rangle 
\end{align}
Note that RHS is a 'zero' in $S$.

To see that $S$ has $8$ elements, note that if $\overline{q(x)}$, where $q(x)$ is of degree$>2$ lies in $S$ then $q(x)$ can be reduced modulo $p(x)$ to get $q(x)=p(x) a(x)+b(x)$, where $b(x)=0$ or degree b(x)<degree $p(x)=3$. It follows that $\overline {q(x)}= q(x)+\langle p(x) \rangle= b(x)+p(x)a(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle= b(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle=\overline{b(x)}$.

Since $b(x)$ is of degree at most $2$, it follows that $b(x)$ is of the form $dx^2+ex+f$. Note that each of $d,e$ or $f$ has two choices (as they are in $F_2$) so maximum number of elements in $S$ is $2^3=8$.

The only way when the number of elements in $S$ is less than $8$ is when any two elements in $S$ are equal (i.e., there is some sort of 'collapsing'). Now, show that there is no collapsing and you are done.

Comment: Why do the elements of $S$ have to look like $ax^2+bx+c+\langle p(x) \rangle$. Why can't $x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$ be one of the equivalence classes of $S$? $x^4$ belongs to $Z_2[x]$ & and can be added to $\langle x^3+x+1 \rangle$ to get one of the cosets. Considering that, I don't see how $S$ has only 8 elements - it would have far, far more elements.

Comment: @user93353: The point is as you have mentioned in OP also that the elements of S are equivalence classes. $\overline{x^4+x^3+x+1}$ is indeed in $S$ but it can be shown to be equal to some element of the form $\overline{ax^2+bx+c}$. To see this, divide $x^4+x^3+x+1$ by $p(x)$ and obtain by Euclid algorithm that $x^4+x^3+x+1=p(x) q(x)+r(x)$, where degree r(x)< degree $p(x)=3$. So in bar notation, one has $\overline {x^4+x^3+x+1}=\overline {r(x)}\quad $ (note that $\overline{p(x)q(x)+r(x)}=\overline{r(x)}$).

Comment: You are right, it's part of an equivalence class. Let me ponder over your reply some more.

Comment: @user93353: I have edited my answer to include an outline to show that $S$ has $8$ elements.

Comment: I have pondered :-). Your answer is really good - thank you!!! This is non-trivial stuff which should have been included in the video. I have a couple of questions however about your answer.

Comment: 1) I don't understand the collapsing part you talked about (i.e it's the opposite question of what you proposed - you said I should prove it doesn't collapse). Each element is an equivalence class of an expression in a variable (x) - so with any particular value (say x= 0), I don't even understand how such expressions would collapse in the first place. And I feel collapsing for particular values (like x=0) shouldn't be relevant

Comment: 2) Though I understand that your proof of RHS is zero, I feel a little confused about the concept of a root which is a variable - a root is always a constant in my mind! For e.g. the roots of $x^2-4$  are {2, -2} - I am unable to understand how either $[\bar x]$ or $x$ - can be a root of $x^3 + x + 1$

Comment: 1) By collapsing, I meant that $S$ has atmost $8$ elements (note the possible number of choices for $d,e$ and $f$) and that it can be shown that if any two of these elements are taken then they turn out to be not equal to each other (no collapsing). Example: The elements $2x^3+2x+3+\langle p(x)\rangle$ and $x^3+x+1+\langle p(x) \rangle$ are the same (that is, two seemingly different elements are the same thing, i.e, collapses into one).

Comment: 2) What is a constant? In $S$, $\overline x$ is a zero of $p(t)$ (that is, $\overline x$ is an element of S which if put in $p(t)$ gives zero, the zero of S).

Comment: `What is a constant?` - a constant is something whose value you know - i.e. the roots of $x^2 - 4$ are ${2, -2}$. With $[\bar x]$ you are still stuck with something whose value you do not know

Comment: Also re the expansion of $(\bar x)^3+\bar x+1$

$(\bar x)^3 = (x + \langle p(x) \rangle)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2\langle p(x) \rangle + 3x(\langle p(x) \rangle)^2 + (\langle p(x) \rangle)^3 = x^3 + \langle p(x) \rangle + \langle p(x) \rangle + \langle p(x) \rangle = x^3 + \langle p(x) \rangle$ - (because $\langle p(x) \rangle$ absorbs all other terms in multiplication)

To this add $(x + \langle p(x) \rangle) + 1$, & you would get RHS as $x^3 + x + 1$
How did you get RHS as $\langle p(x) \rangle + x^3 + x + 1$ - where did I go wrong?

Comment: I considered $\langle p(x) \rangle + \langle p(x) \rangle = 2 * \langle p(x) \rangle$ & since it's $Z_2$, 2 becomes 0, so I considered  $2 * \langle p(x) \rangle$ as 0. Is this wrong?

Comment: @user93353: That’s wrong. Note that S is a ring which by definition is closed under addition. And every element in S is of the form ‘something from $F_2[x]$’+ $\langle p(x)\rangle$. I think explicit mention of this result will clear up your confusion:  Two  cosets $a(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle$ and $b(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle$ are equal iff $a(x)-b(x)$ lies in $\langle p(x)\rangle$.

Comment: This is what I am unable to figure out - In $Z_2$ what is $\langle p(x) \rangle + \langle p(x) \rangle$ or what is $\langle p(x) \rangle + \langle p(x) \rangle + \langle p(x) \rangle$

Comment: What is the result of adding an Ideal to itself - $I + I$ or $I + I + I + I + I$?

Comment: @user93353: It is true that $I+I=I$. You should try to prove that.

Comment: $I$ is Ideal of Ring $R$. Let element of $I = ma$  $\{m \in Z, a \in R\}$, also Element of $I = na \{n \in Z, a \in R\}$,$I + I = ma+nb$ - ma is an element in I, na is also element in I & because of closure $ma+nb$ is also $\in I$  So $I + I = I$. Is this right?

Comment: @user93353: That looks wrong. The statement is true for any ideal and you seem to be trying to prove it for principal ideals only.  Take any $x,y\in I$ then $x+y\in I$ by closure. So $I+I\subset I$.  And for any $z\in I, z=z+0\subset I+I\implies I\subset I+I.$